# Is "both" incorrect when it refers to "different" things?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

Is it correct to use the word "both" when referring to different things?

For example:

> The twins both went to different colleges

> Both David's hands worked at different tasks

I would have thought that it would be correct to use the word "each" instead of "both".

I have come across this a number of times and I'm wondering if I am simply too pedantic.

Comment: The other reading for the first sentence would be rendered 'The twins went to different colleges' (or 'The twins did not attend the same college' for absolute clarification). // As WV implies, the second sentence would be rephrased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the intended meaning. In the first one each twin went to more than one college: Alex went to colleges A, B, C... and similar for Bob.

The second one sounds unnatural. If you are talking about David's hands, then you don't need to say both.

**Both** is a collective noun.

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/both) has an interesting counter-example though:

> I think it's important to listen to both sides of the argument.

Comment: It's a determiner when used before a NP. I think I'd say when used after a NP also (Both the twins went ... / The twins both went ...).

Comment: As I thought. The second one is a direct quote from a book I just finished - I added the "(his)" for clarity. Also, in the first one it is meant to mean that each of them only went to one college just not the same as the other.

Comment: Then the first one is incorrect. You can disambiguate with "The twins each went to a different college". Your 'both' implies they did the same thing: went to [various] colleges.

Comment: I have a prescription that reads "Place one drop in both eyes...". I cringe every time I see it.

Comment: @JimMack hah! Is half a drop in each eye even achievable?

Comment: @WeatherVane - I can't imagine -- how big is half a drop?

Comment: @JimMack You cringe because of the instructions or because of the drops themselves?

Comment: @JimMack I was thinking about the difficulty of cutting a tomato pip.